# ¿Por qué un archivo al abrirlo con LiveServer muestra los cambios y sin LiverServe no?

Tags: vscode

acabo de tener un problema al intentar abrir un archivo .html sin usar LiveServer y me llevo la sorpresa de que no se muestra ningún cambio que le fui haciendo, por ejemplo, utilice un navbar de Bootstrap y al realizar cambios del css pasa esto, arriba es como se ve con LiveServer y abajo sin, si alguien tiene idea de que esta pasando aca y me da una mano se lo agradecería: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas usando visual studio code?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a los cambios que haces en código no los visualizas en tu navegador incluso después de refrescar? Con LiveServer ves los cambios porque esa es una de sus funciones, no tener que refrescar.